# What is `mt=8` in iTunes links for the App Store?

Tags: hyperlink, app-store, itunes

Does anyone know the significance of the `mt` parameter in App Store Links?

Sample link:
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=337319445&mt=8

It seems that any value will work, like `mt=0`, `mt=999`, etc.

Comment: It seems that Apple is changing the link format to a more friendly look, without the cryptic id & mt part, so I don't think it's going to be of much relevance soon.

Comment: New SEO links on iTunes still have the mt=8 parameter but the link works with or without it.  I'm not sure what effect leaving it off does.

Comment: I missed this question because it doesn't mention *App Store* (two words). Similar, and answered in Ask Different: [What's the meaning/use of ?mt=8 and ?mt=12 in iTunes Preview and Mac App Store Preview URLs?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/63992/8546) (2012-09-14)

Comment: Are ?mt= still relevant with the new https://apps.apple.com/ links ? I cannot find any info on that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 242):

Apple designates a number of different Media Types (mt values):

```
1   Music
2   Podcasts
3   Audiobooks
4   TV Shows
5   Music Videos
6   Movies
7   iPod Games
8   Mobile Software Applications
9   Ringtones
10  iTunes U
11  E-Books
12  Desktop Apps
```

So, to answer your question, the "mt=8" in iTunes links simply identifies it as being of type 'Mobile Software Applications'.

Comment: Thanks, that was informational. Do you also know what the 'ls=1' parameter does?

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. For the commenter above, in case you haven't figured out, `ls=1` means the URL will try and open iTunes and follow the link. If `ls=1` is not included it will simply load the web page for that particular media asset.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I wish this was marked as correct answer though... @monkeyboy ?

Comment: Does anybody knows what the **uo** parameter means? If I generate a link for an app using the [iTunes Link Generator](http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com) it adds a `uo=4` at the end of the URL.

Comment: @FabianFernandez See here. Its all about affiliation --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437785/what-does-the-uo-4-parameter-in-an-itunes-link-specify

Answer (score 36):

Some people noted the you can actually drop the *mt* part of the link and you still end up on the expected page. This is correct, but on iOS it is helpful to attach the *mt* tag to tell the OS to what app to switch. When you don't add the *mt* part and you link to an app the OS will first fire up the iTunes app. This one then figures out that the link points to an app and then switches over to the App Store app.

Therefore it is good practice to enhance the experience for the user by adding the correct *mt* tag to your iTunes URLs.

Answer (score 29):

> **Parameters**:
>
> **I** – Identifier: The “I” parameter includes the ID of a specific item
>   in a collection.  For example a track in an album or the episode in
>   season of a TV show.
>
> **MT** – Media Type: The MT parameter indicates which type of media the
>   hyperlink is pointing to. The types and codes you could see are listed
>   below (however, besides 8, 11, and 12 these parameters are often not
>   included, or necessary).
>
> 1 – Music
>
> 2 – Podcasts
>
> 3 –  Audiobooks
>
> 4 – TV Shows
>
> 5 – Music Videos
>
> 6 –  Movies
>
> 7 – iPod Games
>
> 8 – Mobile Software Applications / loads in the App
>   Store on iOS
>
> 9 – Ringtones
>
> 10 – iTunes U
>
> 11 – E-Books / loads in the
>   iBookstore on iOS
>
> 12 – Desktop Apps / loads in the Mac App Store in OS
>   X
>
> Note: The MT parameter is crucial when creating your links for items
>   not in the iTunes Store. In iOS and OS X this parameter tells the
>   operating system which specific store to open to handle the link, and
>   if it’s not built correctly, the customer may see an error instead of
>   the correct item. For example, you can’t open a Mac App link in the
>   iTunes Store and if the link points to the incorrect store (or is not
>   there), there’s an interrupted user experience and a potentially lost
>   conversion.
>
> **LS** – Load Store: This parameter, with the value of “1”
>   (which means “true” in the coding world), tells the Preview Page to
>   also load the item in the iTunes Store (inside the iTunes desktop
>   application). If you don’t use either an affiliate parameter or the LS
>   parameter, the link will only take the user to the Preview Page in
>   their browser. This isn’t ideal because it forces the user to then go
>   through another click to actually purchase the product, which
>   potentially lowers your conversation rate since it’s more work for
>   them. We recommend always using either the LS parameter or affiliate
>   the link to alleviate this.  Because Preview Pages are desktop
>   specific (you don’t see them in iOS) this parameter doesn’t appear to
>   be useful for links that only exist in the mobile ecosystem.
>
> **UO** –
>   Unique Origin: This parameter identifies the tool or sources used to
>   generated the link itself (e.g. RSS Feed Generator, Search API,
>   Enterprise Partner Feed, etc.). This helps identify where the link
>   came from for your benefit, but doesn’t actually affect the end user
>   experience. This can be removed if necessary to tidy up the link.
>
> **Affiliate Specific Parameters**
>
> **AT** – Affiliate Token: PHG’s affiliate token.
>
> **CT** – Campaign Token: Also for PHG. This is a value to help you determine (or set) the “campaign” of the link (similar to the “Enhanced Publisher Interface” from Tradedoubler or the “Signature Tracking” from LinkShare). With GeoRiot, this parameter is set with the TRACK parameter and is synonymous with “Tracking Tag”.
>
> **TDUID** – TradeDoubler Unique Identifier: This is used for affiliate links that skip the TradeDoubler redirect. For those links, this value is consistent per account but needs to be set up with Tradedoubler in advance.
>
> **partnerId**: Previously used to identify each of the original affiliate networks, but currently only used for TradeDoubler, which has an ID of 2003.  Note that the capitalization of this parameter is important.
>
> **affId** – Affiliate ID: After a Tradedoubler link is processed via their redirect the final link will include the affid parameter.  The value included will be the same as the “a” value in the original Tradedoubler affiliate link that was resolved.

[Source](https://blog.geni.us/2013/12/06/parameter-cheat-sheet-for-itunes-and-app-store-links/)

Answer (score 17):

The mt = Media Type.  mt=8 == media=software

Valid media types are : movie, podcast, music, musicVideo, audiobook,
shortFilm, tvShow, software, all

presumably, movie = 1, podcast=2, music=3, musicVideo=4 and so on until software=8

I think anything other numeric value (>8) than those valid ones will return all.

Answer (score 11):

I USED to think you could strip the mt and ls parameters without any impact.

I just discovered a case where that failed... it worked find on iPhones without the parameters but not on iPads.  On an iPad it launched iTunes, but never brought you to the right app.

I'm not sure why... but, I put them back in and it works fine on iPhone and iPad.

I didn't experiment with stripping just the mt vs. the ls.  I suspect it's the ls=1 that is the culprit... though I'm not sure why iPhone would be more forgiving than iPad.

Answer (score 5):

The app on Appstore has specific URL format
http://itunes.apple.com/[country-code]/app/[app-name]/id+[id_value]?mt=[1...12]

1. country-code can be *us* for *united states*, *in* for *india* etc
2. *mt stands for Media Type*
3. *Value for mt can be anything from 1 to 12 and each assigned to specific category*

   i. **8 for iOS apps**

   ii. **12 for Mac apps**

Answer (score 4):

When you've got a unique id already like:
itunes.apple.com/us/app/rogo/id400118698?mt=8

it seems to work fine without it, ie:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rogo/id400118698

In this new URL format, only the id matters - the app name "rogo" is ignored.

Comment: The app name is so much ignored that this url http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id400118698 also works

Answer (score 1):

Note that some browsers will respect preferences for handling different media types -- ie it can have unintended/unexpected consequences if you strip it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Just a note, typically I think these sorts of answers are more like "comments" and less like "answers". I know you can't make comments yet so just letting you know for future reference!