# In-App review feature in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, review

I have recently seen in some Apps that review and rating (with 5 stars) can be integrated into the app. Does anyone have an idea how this is done? e.g. with a http request?

More specific: Can I create a view in my App with a UITextField and a Button, so that when the user writes his review in the textfield and click send, the review should be posted to the "Customer Reviews" in the App Store? and the rating should also be done inside the App similarly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I did this with my own app. I have a rating button that hits the following method on click:

```
- (IBAction) reviewPressed: (id) source { 
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=341086403"; 
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

You will need to replace the ID in the URL with your own App ID.  For new apps, this presents you with a chick-and-egg problem - you don't have an ID until the App goes live.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chris, I'm hoping to rate and write the review inside the App, not just to open the review page in app store. Is this possible?

Comment: seems there is no way to do it. i'd accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: getting alert .. "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Comment: When you create app in itunesConnect, you have got AppleID even if this app not in App Store. As a result, not presents "chick-and-egg" problem

Answer (score 6):

You can get your application ID by going in the process of submitting an app but choose to upload the app binary later. You will then get the app ID and thus add it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think its late but this is the best solution.
You can use below url to directly send user to write a review page on App Store. Just need to replace **application id**.

> itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id1136613532?action=write-review&mt=8

Example :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id1136613532?action=write-review&mt=8"]];
```

Here My Application Id is **1136613532**. You can replace it with yours.
Tested in iOS 10.3

Comment: What's the effect of the `mt=8` parameter?

Comment: Found it myself, its the [media type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781427/what-is-mt-8-in-itunes-links-for-the-appstore/6774015#6774015)

Comment: Ok.. If this link helps you then please upvote answer.