# Why do Apple iTunes App Store links end in mt=8

Tags: hyperlink, app-store, itunes-store, itunes-app

Does anyone know what the mt=8 parameter is on the end of what appears to be all iTunes App Store links? More specifically, my question is do I need to add that parameter when linking to apps on the store from my websites?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781427/what-is-mt-8-in-itunes-links-for-the-appstore

Comment: Thanks @Jaro - I couldn't find this question/answer either for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT stand for "**Media Type**"

Here is list for Media Types

1 =  Music

2 =  Podcast

3 =  Audiobook

4 =  TV Show

5 =  Music Videos

6 =  Movie

7 =  iPod Game

8 =  Mobile Application

9 =  Ringtone

10 = iTunes U

11 =  E-Book

12 = Desktop Application