# Which are the parameters of the AppStore API Call URL?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

So, I have found this URL that does exactly what I want, or so I believe..

> being **APP_ID** my app's ID in **Itunes Connect**

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8&id=APP_ID
```

Here as I have managed to find out answers on the web, `type=Purple+Software` is for IPhone Apps and appears like `viewContentsUserReviews` leads me to the **Rate and Review** page of the **AppStore** for my app

What's the question here, there is a shorter version of the string to reach the app on the appStore:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID
```

This one appears to have several options, such as:

```
?ls=1
?mt=8
?at=10l6dK
```

But I have no clue of what those parameters are meant to do (and I wanna know), also, how can I use this shorter version of the string to define my **Affiliate Code** or **Campaign Code** of ITunes? How can I use this shorter version to redirect the user directly into the **Rate an Review** tab, such as the long version does.

> So, summing up, What are all the parameters that can be passed into
>   this url API call?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are used for SEO optimization in the web version starting with `http://`, so they're unnecessary for App Store iOS links (`itms-apps://`).
By the way, in this case, these parameters are used for:

- `mt=8`: content media type (8 = apps, 1 = music, etc. - [see reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781427/what-is-mt-8-in-itunes-links-for-the-appstore))
- `ls=1`: the URL will try to open in iTunes

Please note that the long URL you specified doesn't work since iOS 7, [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag).