# How to add Rate the app Component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to add "Rate the app" Component in React Native? I want to implement the Rating feature in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a "Rate this app" link in React Native app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612383/how-to-make-a-rate-this-app-link-in-react-native-app)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html):

```
Linking.openURL('itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/myiosappid?mt=64')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) like that

`Linking.openURL('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111')`

where 111111111 is ur appId

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for that now

[react-native-in-app-review](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-in-app-review)